# Modifying a question [beyond recognition]

Tags: support, questions

I asked a question on SO yesterday. While framing the question, I managed to solve it partially. When I look at that question now, I feel that it can be trimmed to make it easier to answer.

So far, only 17 views, no comments and no answers. Are the following situations acceptable:

1. Edit the unnoticed question into something totally different
2. Edit the question to something almost similar to the original version - A specific question compared to the somewhat broader question I was asking initially.

Comment: The rubber duck came through, then?

Comment: @MartinJames apparently, yes.

Comment: If there are no answers that your edit would invalidate... go nuts. Personally, I'd go with option #2 - add more detail to make the question more specific.

Comment: I'm having trouble understand why you think could have this choice. You solved it partially but not entirely. If you had answered it entirely you could have self-answered and not have to edit anything. But since you partially solved it, the way to go is to improve the question based on what you understand now.

Comment: `1` is out pf pure curiosity. But I agree with @AnnaLear that #2 is better

Answer (score 6):

Option 2 seems to be the safest. Number 1 may seem viable if there are no answers, but you can never be sure if at the time of editing your question there is no one writing an answer to the previous version.

You can also choose to close/delete the original question and post a new one.